# Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present when I request from Angular 4

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, angular2-jwt

I can do a request uploading a file from Postman, but when I do the request from Angular, it is returned the WARN "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present"

It follows my resource in API.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Conteudo> publicaConteudo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    /* ANYTHING */
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new Conteudo());
}
```

And my service in Angular. I'm using JWT, but I also trying to do the request using HttpClient.

```
upload(file: File, conteudo: Conteudo): Promise<any> {
   let formData: FormData = new FormData();

   formData.append('file', file, file.name);

  /* USING JWT
   return this.http.post(this.conteudoUrl, formData)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json());
  */
     let h1 = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'));
     const req = new HttpRequest('POST',this.conteudoUrl, formData, {
         headers: h1
  });
  return this.httpClient.request(req).toPromise();
 }
```

And how I can do in Postman

[image]

I tried many solutions that I found, as create a Bean MultipartResolver and others, but any solve my problem and what I think more interesting is that it works fine in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

In your AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer class do you have this method?:

```
@Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter("UTF-8");
        encodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[]{new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"), 
            new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter(),encodingFilter, new MultipartFilter()};
    }
```

maybe you haven´t registered the multipart filter. Hope this help.